# How to wait for thread to initialize variable in Kotlin?

Tags: multithreading, javafx, concurrency, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have an JavaFX-based application, written in Kotlin. JavaFX runs in a separate thread by default, and I want to ensure that the variable that is initialized in the main thread is ready when JavaFX reaches the part where it uses that variable.

Java has `wait` and `notify` methods that I'd use on that variable, but they aren't available in Kotlin.

I also looked into Kotlin coroutines, but they seem to be built around task dependency (i.e. one task can wait for another), but they don't work so simply with variables, and are using coroutines instead of threads, i.e. if I use coroutines to coordinate my variables, JavaFX still runs on a separate thread, which cannot be coordinated together with coroutines (or am I missing something?).

Comment: I suspect you might want to check [this implementation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/ui/kotlinx-coroutines-javafx) of JavaFX-specific coroutine context.

Comment: @yegodm can you expand on this? I think that this could be the solution, I just don't know where to start to implement this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still [use `wait` and `notifiy` in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#waitnotify), though not recommended.

You could also use [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: `CountDownLatch` seems like a "dumb" solution, but it works sufficiently well for this issue...

Comment: `CompletableFuture` could be a better choice.